# Identity SignInManager can't sign in admin user created by seeder ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to seed an admin user with role assigned through a seeder class. User gets created successfully (password is hashed in DB) but when I try to login with it I get "Invalid login attempt". Here is the code for all of the classes and configurations I  made.

```
    public abstract class BaseSeeder : ISeeder
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        private readonly IConfiguration config;


        protected BaseSeeder(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            Logger = logger;
            this.config = config;
        }

        protected string AdminEmail => this.config.GetSection("AdminEmailAddres").Value;

        protected string AdminPassword => this.config.GetSection("AdminPassword").Value;

        protected IEnumerable<string> AvailableRoles => new string[] { this.Roles.AdminRole, this.Roles.UserRole, this.Roles.CustomerRole };

        protected RoleModel Roles => this.config.GetSection("AvailableRoles").GetChildren().ToList()
        .Select(v => new RoleModel
        {
            AdminRole = v.GetValue<string>("AdminRole"),
            UserRole = v.GetValue<string>("UserRole"),
            CustomerRole = v.GetValue<string>("CustomerRole"),
        }).FirstOrDefault();

        protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager => this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        protected RoleManager<ApplicationRole> RoleManager => this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();

        protected ILogger Logger { get; }

        public abstract Task SeedAsync(ApplDBContext dataBase, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration config);
```

This is the Base seeder class. Here are the Role and Admin seeders:

```
  public class RoleSeeder : BaseSeeder
    {
        public RoleSeeder(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger logger, IConfiguration config)
            : base(serviceProvider, logger, config)
        {
        }

        public override async Task SeedAsync(ApplDBContext dataBase, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration config)
        {
            foreach (var roleName in this.AvailableRoles)
            {
                if (await this.RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName))
                    continue;

                var result = await this.RoleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole(roleName));

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                    throw new Exception(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Errors.Select(v => v.Description)));

                this.Logger.LogInformation(@$"Seeding ""{roleName}"" role has been succesful.");
            }
        }
    }
public class AdminUserSeeder : BaseSeeder
    {
        public AdminUserSeeder(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger logger, IConfiguration config)
            : base(serviceProvider, logger, config)
        {
        }

        public override async Task SeedAsync(ApplDBContext dataBase, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration config)
        {
            if (await this.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(this.AdminEmail) == null)
            {
                var adminUser = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = "admin",
                    Email = this.AdminEmail,
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    PhoneNumber = "+35796842165",
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                };

                var result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, this.AdminPassword);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, this.Roles.AdminRole);

                this.Logger.LogInformation(@$"Seeding admin user has been successful");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the DataSeeder which is configured in the Startup class:

```
   public class DataSeeder : ISeeder
    {
        public async Task SeedAsync(ApplDBContext dataBase, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration config)
        {
            if (dataBase == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataBase));

            if (serviceProvider == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));

            var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(typeof(DataSeeder));

            var seeders = new List<ISeeder>()
            {
                new RoleSeeder(serviceProvider,logger,config),
                new AdminUserSeeder(serviceProvider,logger,config),
            };

            foreach (var item in seeders) await item.SeedAsync(dataBase, serviceProvider, config);


            await dataBase.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

     }
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                var dataBase = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplDBContext>();
                new DataSeeder()
                    .SeedAsync(dataBase, serviceScope.ServiceProvider, this.configuration)
                    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
```

After user is created and assigned to the admin role why do I get the "Invalid login attempt"
[This is the Identity Login pageModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJDsD.png)

Comment: Your example shows your username is `admin` but your image suggests you're trying to log in with an email address.

Comment: You are very correct... It works.. thanks......